# How to iterate over CustomCollection generic type in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, generics, swift2

I have a custom collection class with an embedded array written in Obj-c. The class implements NSFastEnumerator protocol in order to be iterable in Obj-c.

For my Swift classes I had to add the following code based on apporaches on SOF.

```
extension CustomCollection: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}
```

Which again makes it iterable in Swift classes.

All is good until I need to use this class as a Generic type in one of my Swift base classes.

```
class SomeBaseClass<T: CustomCollection> {
    typealias Collection = T
    var model: Collection?
    // Implementation goes here
}
```

When I try to iterate over my 'model' property, I get Command Signal Failure Error during build.

Any idea how this needs to be done and whether it's even possible to be done?

Running XCode 7 beta 6 and Swift 2.0

Thanks.

Comment: Does changing `typealias Collection = CustomCollection` to `typealias Collection = T` fix the problem?

Comment: oisdk Sorry that is a typo. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with Xcode 7.0.1:

First the `CustomCollection` class. I've keep it simple since I don't know what yours is doing.

```
public class CustomCollection: NSFastEnumeration
{
    var array: NSMutableArray = []

    @objc public func countByEnumeratingWithState(state: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSFastEnumerationState>, objects buffer: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>, count len: Int) -> Int {
        var index = 0
        if state.memory.state != 0 {
            index = Int(state.memory.state)
        }
        if index >= self.array.count {
            return 0
        }
        var array = Array<AnyObject?>()
        while (index < self.array.count && array.count < len)
        {
            array.append(self.array[index++])
        }
        let cArray: UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?> = UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>.alloc(array.count)
        cArray.initializeFrom(array)

        state.memory.state = UInt(index)
        state.memory.itemsPtr = AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>.init(cArray)
        return array.count
    }
}
```

Then there's the code you provided.

```
extension CustomCollection: SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> NSFastGenerator {
        return NSFastGenerator(self)
    }
}

class SomeBaseClass<T: CustomCollection>
{
    typealias Collection = T
    var model: Collection?
}
```

With all this, I'm able to run the following

```
var myModel = CustomCollection()
myModel.array.addObject("This")
myModel.array.addObject("is")
myModel.array.addObject("a")
myModel.array.addObject(["complex", "test"])
var myVar = SomeBaseClass()
myVar.model = myModel

for myObject in myVar.model!
{
    print(myObject)
}
```

And the console prints

```
This
is
a
(
    complex,
    test
)
```

Hope it helps!